# Get a list of results and get the total in one query

Tags: mysql, go

I have logic that is meant for pagination, and it works perfectly fine as is. This question is meant for optimization/improvement in regards to how I'm doing something.

I am running two queries to get a result set. The first query gets all items by limit and offset, the second query gets the total count. I need this total to do math for pagination links in the presentation layer.

I want to avoid running two queries, and combine them into one if possible.

For example, if there is 100 items in the database and I run the query below with the `LimitStartIndex` at 1 and `LimitStopIndex` at 20, then the query should return 20 results and a count of 100. I currently achieve this in two separate queries just fine, but again I want to do it in one query.

Here is my current setup (using Golang):

```
var items []*Item
err := r.db.Select(&items, `
    SELECT item.*
    FROM item
    JOIN user
        ON user.username = ?
    JOIN user_item
        ON user_item.item_id = item.id
        AND user_item.user_id = user.id
    ORDER BY item.id DESC
    LIMIT ?,?
`, username, pagination.LimitStartIndex, pagination.LimitStopIndex)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

var total int
err = r.db.Get(&total, `
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM item
    JOIN user
        ON user.username = ?
    JOIN user_item
        ON user_item.item_id = item.id
        AND user_item.user_id = user.id
`, username)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

result := &domain.PaginationResult{
    Items: items,
    Total: total,
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT item.*, COUNT(DISTINCT item.id) AS _count
FROM item
JOIN user
    ON user.username = ?
JOIN user_item
    ON user_item.item_id = item.id
    AND user_item.user_id = user.id
ORDER BY item.id DESC
LIMIT ?,?
```

However I receive this error:

> Error 1140: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of
>   SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'mytable.item.id'; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Not giving the answer here, but are you sure it wouldn't be better to do the counting on the application layer?

Comment: I want to get a count of *all* items for the given query, not just the count of the results returned with the `LIMIT` contraints. Look at the second query in the first code example and you will see what I mean; it doesn't use `LIMIT`.

Comment: What's wrong in running two queries?

Comment: Take a look at the information functions - specifically FOUND_ROWS

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Nothing, necessarily. I just figured if I could make it one instead of two, that'd be better.

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` is an option, but (from my experience) two queries are usually faster. At least for low offsets when supported by indexes. Note that for the COUNT query you don't need to join the `item` table. You only need  to count the rows in the `user_item` table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah great point, hadn't thought of that. That will at least reduce the second query. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . Actually on second thought, there will indeed need to be a join on some of the `COUNT` queries. In some cases, I don't just want to know how many `user_item` rows there are, I want to know how many `user_item` rows there are while other conditions are true (such as where the `username` equals something). That is why I do the join, so I can only select the `user_item` rows by a given user. The business logic is "Get an item feed by username"

Comment: According to me you should run 2 queries to avoid the false result. Consider a scenario where your offset > total number of records. Query will not return any row(s) and this will make your `totalCount` as 0 which is actually false (as you have records > 0, but it didn't return those just because offset value was greater than total records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to add 'group by' in the query. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
SELECT item.*, COUNT(*) AS _count
FROM item
JOIN user
    ON user.username = ?
JOIN user_item
    ON user_item.item_id = item.id
    AND user_item.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY item.id        
ORDER BY item.id DESC
LIMIT ?, ?
```